# Global fit coupled odes system lmfit

Tags: global, ode, minimize, lmfit

I'm trying to get the global fit of multiple set of data considering a system of 4 coupled ODEs.

I have the working code that solves the system of 4 coupled ODEs for a single set of data, and I have the working code that do the global fit with an arbitrary function (but not using odeint).
My problem is that I'm not able to merge the two codes...

**Code for coupled ODEs**

```
t =
data=

def gauss(x, amp, sigma, center):
    """Gaussian lineshape."""
    return amp * np.exp(-(x-center)**2 / (2.*sigma**2))

def f(xs, t, ps):
    """Lotka-Volterra predator-prey model."""
    try:
        amp = ps['amp'].value
        center = ps['center'].value
        sigma = ps['sigma'].value
        T1 = ps['T1'].value
        Teq = ps['Teq'].value

    except Exception:
        amp, center, sigma, T1, Teq = ps
    s0,s1,s2,s3 = xs
    return [- gauss(t,amp,sigma,center) * (s0-s1),\
            gauss(t,amp,sigma,center) * (s0-s1) - s1/T1,\
           (s1/T1 - s2/Teq),\
           (s2/Teq)]

def g(t, x0, ps):
    x = odeint(f, x0, t, args=(ps,))
    return x

def residual(ps, ts, data):
    x0 = ps['s0'].value, ps['s1'].value, ps['s2'].value, ps['s3'].value
    b = ps['b'].value
    model = (((g(ts, x0, ps)[:,0]-g(ts, x0, ps)[:,1]+g(ts, x0, ps)[:,2]+b*g(ts, x0, ps)[:,3]))**2)/((g(ts, x0, ps)[0,0]))**2
    return (model - data).ravel()

# set parameters incluing bounds
params = Parameters()
params.add('s0', value=1, vary=False)
params.add('s1', value=0, vary=False)
params.add('s2', value=0, vary=False)
params.add('s3', value=0, vary=False)
params.add('amp', value=0.02)
params.add('center', value=5)
params.add('sigma', value=0.1)
params.add('T1', value=0.3)
params.add('Teq', value=0.7)
params.add('b', value=-1)

# fit model and find predicted values
result = minimize(residual, params, args=(t, data), method='leastsq')
final = data + result.residual.reshape(data.shape)
```

Considering the code here: https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/examples/example_fit_multi_datasets.html

I've tried to do by myself the code for global fit in this case

```
def gauss(x, amp, sigma, center):
    """Gaussian lineshape."""
    return amp * np.exp(-(x-center)**2 / (2.*sigma**2))

def f(xs, t, ps):
    """Lotka-Volterra predator-prey model."""
    try:
        amp = ps['amp'].value
        center = ps['center'].value
        sigma = ps['sigma'].value
        T1 = ps['T1'].value
        Teq = ps['Teq'].value

    except Exception:
        amp, center, sigma, T1, Teq = ps
    s0,s1,s2,s3 = xs
    return [- gauss(t,amp,sigma,center) * (s0-s1),\
            gauss(t,amp,sigma,center) * (s0-s1) - s1/T1,\
           (s1/T1 - s2/Teq),\
           (s2/Teq)]

def g(t, x0, params):
    """
    Solution to the ODE x'(t) = f(t,x,k) with initial condition x(0) = x0
    """
    x = odeint(f, x0, t, args=(params,))
    return x

def testmodel(params, ts, data):
    x0 = params['s0'].value, params['s1'].value, params['s2'].value, params['s3'].value
    b = params['b'].value
    model = (((g(ts, x0, params)[:,0]-g(ts, x0, params)[:,1]+g(ts, x0, params)[:,2]+b*g(ts, x0, params)[:,3]))**2)/((g(ts, x0, params)[0,0]))**2
    return model


def testmodel_dataset(params, i, x):
    """Calculate Gaussian lineshape from parameters for data set."""
    x0 = params[f's0_{i+1}'], params[f's1_{i+1}'], params[f's2_{i+1}'], params[f's3_{i+1}']
    amp = params[f'amp_{i+1}']
    center = params[f'center_{i+1}']
    sigma = params[f'sigma_{i+1}']
    T1 = params[f'T1_{i+1}']
    Teq = params[f'Teq_{i+1}']
    b = params[f'b_{i+1}']
    return testmodel(params, x, data)


def objective(params, x, data):
    """Calculate total residual for fits of Gaussians to several data sets."""
    ndata, _ = data.shape
    resid = 0.0*data[:]

    # make residual per data set
    for i in range(ndata):
        resid[i, :] = data[i, :] - testmodel_dataset(params, i, x)

    # now flatten this to a 1D array, as minimize() needs
    return resid.flatten()


fit_params = Parameters()
for iy, y in enumerate(data):
    fit_params.add(f's0_{iy+1}', value=1)
    fit_params.add(f's1_{iy+1}', value=0)
    fit_params.add(f's2_{iy+1}', value=0)
    fit_params.add(f's3_{iy+1}', value=0)
    fit_params.add(f'amp_{iy+1}', value=0.5)
    fit_params.add(f'center_{iy+1}', value=0.5)
    fit_params.add(f'sigma_{iy+1}', value=0.5)
    fit_params.add(f'T1_{iy+1}', value=0.5)
    fit_params.add(f'Teq_{iy+1}', value=0.4)
    fit_params.add(f'b_{iy+1}', value=0.3)

for iy in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6):
    fit_params[f'sigma_{iy}'].expr = 'sigma_1'
   
out = minimize(objective, fit_params, args=(x, data))
report_fit(out.params)
```

Result -> **KeyError: 's0'**

There is a problem with x0 and s0,s1,s2,s3, population of the four states.
I'm sorry if the question may be very naive...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: As first line in `testmodel`, insert `print(params)`. Or set a breakpoint there and inspect this parameter. Does the key `s0` exist?

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes, you're right. ```s0``` didn't exist, there was ```s0_1```, ```s0_2```, ```s0_3``` and so on. I had to modify ```f```, ```g```, ```testmodel``` including the ```i``` so they match with ```testmodel_dataset```. It works. Thanks a lot :)